# Remove Special Character from String in API

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an API and it response me a string, that string contains a URLs of photos,
but the URLs contains special characters (backslash),

how can I remove that Special Character from String in API?

this is the String :

```
 "photos": 
"[\"uploads\\/products\\/photos\\/9UZGRucASnXoKsn6fnLqLcWYS7Ttb84JPOHOyJR1.jpeg\",\"uploads\\/products\\/photos\\/zjofjxnsjWus210f5S3YuijJMt9wXSnI6frgNRXc.jpeg\",\"uploads\\/products\\/photos\\/BA5oMG3EPVSDmQcLTYH3DZj1igwg4gMUvC6ItxmT.jpeg\",\"uploads\\/products\\/photos\\/gcCyQzli8M4ZGIWfcuU7DKf9C2y8rVxq5OpSHT9w.jpeg\",\"uploads\\/products\\/photos\\/1xPnp6ut6C7wJUlGHqUlnGrL6H3ClIPs0eFM96yc.jpeg\",\"uploads\\/products\\/photos\\/JjlVTcv6YencrYQClxCL2FRzMD6DUelfggtHVHbI.jpeg\",\"uploads\\/products\\/photos\\/b1iroJ8YWMj9PsTmSHML1iRlX3G8ayjYvhNP3bZO.jpeg\",\"uploads\\/products\\/photos\\/jUo1bUWi5bjEkk4c9WyQgGhUNGjqDYuFScildcq2.jpeg\"]",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea really is to use the `replaceAll` method, but you must escape the backslash as it follows:

```
string.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\\'), '')
```

If you don't do so, you are actually escaping your last ` character and will get an error.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a string, you can pass in the url of the photo path in this case to a variable. Then you can use RegExp to replace all occurrences of a certain character in a String.

`final myString = 'abc=';`

`final withoutEquals = myString.replaceAll(RegExp('='), ''); // abc`
In your case:

```
String photoUrl = //Your photo Url
final cutPhotoUrl = photoUrl.replaceAll(RegExp('\'), ''); // Replaces all occurrences of backslash with blank whitespace
```